# Select a feature in arcengine c# project by clicking on it and change the attribute of it programmatically

Tags: c#, arcobjects, esri-arc-engine

I want to click on a feature of shapefile in arc engine c# project and change the selected feature's attributes by code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FeatureClass.serach method  with SpatialFilter.
Via SpatialFilter you can define your clicked point as a geometry of selection area( use intersect relationship).
The answer of the Search method is IFeatureCursor. You can read and update features using FetaureCursor.